# Create dataframe with list comprehension with each column dependent on the previous

Tags: python, list, loops, list-comprehension

I need to create a dataframe with list comprehension whereby each column is equal to a transformation of the previous one.

However, each column is not dependent on the previous.

I only have the first column:

```
0.0229
0.0229
0.0229
```

The formula I want to apply is: -0.0126*(1.22 + horizontal sum of previous columns) + 0.0383

Such that the columns are like the following, all in a one line list comprehension:

```
0        1                          2
0.0229   (-0.0126*(1.22 + col0))  (-0.0126*(1.22 + col0 + col1))
0.0229   (-0.0126*(1.22 + col0))  (-0.0126*(1.22 + col0 + col1))
0.0229   (-0.0126*(1.22 + col0))  (-0.0126*(1.22 + col0 + col1))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your list comprehension, you keep referencing the same column "col1" instead of the previous column.

You can loop and reference the previous column with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [0.0229]*3})
x = -0.0126
y = 1.22
z = 0.0383

for i in range(1,3):
    df[i] = x*(y+df.sum(axis=1))+z

>>> df

        0         1         2
0  0.0229  0.022639  0.022354
1  0.0229  0.022639  0.022354
2  0.0229  0.022639  0.022354
```

If you *must* use a list comprehension, you need to use mathematical induction to figure out how column `n` relates to column 0. In your case it is:

[image]

```
x = -0.0126
y = 1.22
z = 0.0383

new_df = pd.concat([(1+x)**(i-1)*(x*(y+df[0])+z) for i in range(3)],axis=1)

>>> new_df
          0         0         0
0  0.022928  0.022639  0.022354
1  0.022928  0.022639  0.022354
2  0.022928  0.022639  0.022354
```

Comment: You're multiplying by the index i which is 0,1,2. Why would I do that? I don't want my columns to be multiplied by the index

Comment: No. I'm using the values in `df["col"]` and adding 2 to it `i` number of times. Which is essentially what you're doing when you're adding 2 to the "previous" column.

Comment: Sorry I edited as it's supposed to be a multiplication, not a sum

Comment: Still I don't understand. Expenentiating my x results in weird behaviour. My real x is not 2, is -0.01 - therefore if I multiply my column by -0.01 to the power of the range I get random numbers.

Comment: That's why a minimal reproducible example with *representative* data is important. The above code should work regardless of the value of x. Please update your post. Also, why do you *have* to use "a one line list comprehension"?

Comment: Edited, thank you. I need it to be in a list comprehension as I have to do all in one line which will be evalueted by eval function in python